# Foreach not looping through all controls while copying them from one form to another

Tags: c#, forms, foreach, controls

I am trying to copy all controls from a dynamic form to another statically declared form. Curiously exactly half of them are getting copied. The code looks like this-

```
// Constructor of static form
public ApplicationForm(dynamic form)
{
        // Add all controls from the dynamic form to the Application form
        Console.WriteLine("I have total of {0} controls\n", form.Controls.Count);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Control c in form.Controls)
        {
            i++;
            this.Controls.Add(c);
            Console.WriteLine(" Number of controls rem {1}\n",
                              form.Controls.Count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("I added a total of {0} controls and still have {1}\n",i,     
                           form.Controls.Count);
}
```

For one particular example, there were 56 controls at the beginning of the loop and there were 27 still remaining at the completion of the loop. And just to test I added the same for loop again after the first one. This time there were 13 remaining.

Why are only half of the controls getting added? Why is the `foreach` loop exiting prematurely?

**PS**: I reason I am doing this copy is because I do know a way of capturing keystrokes for a dynamic form. For a static form, I can override `ProcessCmdKey` and trap keystrokes but I dont know of any equivalent for dynamic forms

Comment: I expect some enumerator magic. Can you try to first add all controls to a List<Control> and then iterate of that list to add them to the applicationform?

Comment: Are you only looking for the top-level controls or really all? In this case you would need to iterate through the childs aswell. Tell me if Im right with this. Can post some code then.

Comment: Yes, @rene is correct. You are accessing the collection and changing it at the same time (by changing the parent of the control). Please try to put it in a list & check. Please let us know if it worked.

Comment: @rene You are right! It works if I use an intermediate list. Can you elaborate it into an answer, so that I can accept it? Also, very curious to know what happens to child controls of the first level controls? I mean its enough if I copy the uppermost control right? All children will automatically move along with the parent right?

Comment: @C4ud3x Please see my above comment to rene

Comment: I don't see where you are doing any __copying__. I only see you are __moving__ the controls and also modifying the enumarated collection, which is a no-can-do..

Comment: @TaW You are right. I am indeed "moving" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption probably is that this:

```
    foreach (Control c in form.Controls)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(c);
    }
```

only affects ONE ControlColection, namely the collection on `this`. A control however can only have ONE parent. The internals of the `Add` implementation reveals the following:

```
public virtual void Add(Control value)
{
    // skipped stuff
    if (value.parent != null)
    {
        value.parent.Controls.Remove(value);
    }
    base.InnerList.Add(value);
    // many more
 }
```

Notice how the `Add` method calls `Remove` for the parent controlcollection. The `InnerList` is an `ArrayList`. It's size gets reduced on the parent every time you add a control to the other form. Hence you only process half of them.

Before you start adding the Controls copy to a `List<Control>` first and then add the controls from the list to the ApplicationForm.

```
    // copy controls to list
    var list = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control c in form.Controls)
    {
        list.Add(c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("I have total of {0} controls\n", form.Controls.Count);
    int i = 0;
    // iterate over list
    foreach (Control c in list)
    {
        i++;
        this.Controls.Add(c);
        Console.WriteLine(" Number of controls rem {1}\n",
                          form.Controls.Count);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("I added a total of {0} controls and still have {1}\n",i,     
                       form.Controls.Count);
```

Comment: I still am confused about half the no of elements being moved. I can see a positive count on the source form outside the for loop. If so, why did the loop exit? Can you also shed some light on child controls?

Comment: The ArrayList length gets reduced in size with every Add/Remove. Assume there are only 2 controls, after processing the first, the length of the array is now 1, the for loop counter increases to 1 and checks for counter  less than length, which is false, hence the loop exists. I assume child controls of the controls you move/copy are not affected. They are in the control collection of their parent not being the form.

Comment: @PavanManjunath To avoid such confusions, normally the enumerator implementations throw exception if the underlying collection is modified during the enumeration. Interestingly, the one for the `ControlsCollection` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1ac71dc0d6ce7f92 seems to be specifically made to not do that (the base class implementation is following the throw pattern).

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `while (form.Controls.Any()) { this.Controls.Add(form.Controls.First(); }`?

Comment: Sure @corey that is also a way but that is maybe even more confusing than my solution. Yours is probably more memory efficient if that would be a thing here....

Comment: @Corey I am getting ''System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any'' for your solution. ControlCollection does inherit from IEnumerable. I'm not sure why I'm hitting this RunTimeBinderException.

Comment: It is a LInq operator, add `using System.Linq;` Be aware that that implementation relies on the internal implementation detail that the control gets removed from the collection. I don't assume that will change soon but I tend to not rely on those kind of internal workings.